# use bind1st in const memeber function

Tags: c++, linux, stl

```
ClassA & operator << ( ClassA &, int32_t )
{
    ...
}


class ClassMain
{
public:
    insert( ClassA & c ) const;
    ...
private:
    std::set<int> m_setContainer;
};

struct  InsertOpt : binary_function<ClassA, int, ClassA&>
{
        ClassA & operator( )( ClassA & c, int val ) const
        {
                c << val;
                return c;
        }
};

void ClassMain::insert( ClassA & c ) const
{
    // Case I: the for loop works
    for ( std::set<int>::const_iterator iter = m_setContainer.begin( );
          iter != m_setContainer.end( ); ++iter )
    {
            c << *iter; // operator<<( c, *iter );
    }

    // Case II: doesn't work
    for_each( m_setContainer.begin( ), m_setContainer.end( ), bind1st( InsertOpt(), c ) );


}

Error:
../include/c++/4.1.2/bits/stl_function.h:406: error: no match for call to '(const InsertOpt) (const ClassA&, const int&)'
note: candidates are: ClassA& InsertOpt::operator()(ClassA&, int32_t) const
```

Question> Why the compiler looks for `(const ClassA&, const int&)` instead of `ClassA & operator( )( ClassA & c, int val ) const`?

Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't that be `binary_function<ClassA &, int, ClassA &>`?

Comment: In effective STL, Item 40. Make functor classes adaptable, "In general, non-pointer types passed to unary_function or binary_function have consts and references stripped off."

Comment: Either that is incorrect or you are misinterpreting it. There is no magic that allows you to pass a const object as a non-const reference parameter just because you are passing it to a functor.

Comment: Also, I should add that it looks like you are using g++ 4.1, which is rather old at this point. I would try with a newer g++.

Comment: @cdhowie, yes, I am using an old compiler and I have to stick with it due to work. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> "In general, non-pointer types passed to unary_function or
>   binary_function have consts and references stripped off."

That is not correct. It would imply that some decay is applied to the template arguments of `binary_function` (e.g. via `std::decay`). But the standard defines `binary_function` quite unequivocally in [depr.base]:

```
template <class Arg1, class Arg2, class Result>
struct binary_function
{
    typedef Arg1 first_argument_type;
    typedef Arg2 second_argument_type;
    typedef Result result_type;
};
```

And `binder1st` is defined in [depr.lib.binder.1st]:

> ```
> template <class Fn>
> class binder1st : public unary_function<typename Fn::second_argument_type,
>                                         typename Fn::result_type>
> {
> protected:
>     Fn op;
>     typename Fn::first_argument_type value;
>
> public:
>     binder1st(const Fn& x,
>               const typename Fn::first_argument_type& y);
>
>     typename Fn::result_type
>     operator()(const typename Fn::second_argument_type& x) const;
>     typename Fn::result_type
>     operator()(typename Fn::second_argument_type& x) const;
> };
> ```
>
> 1. The constructor initializes `op` with `x` and value with `y`.
> 2. `operator()` returns `op(value,x)`.

As you can see the argument to the stored function object is `value`, which is of type `typename Fn::first_argument_type`. **But also note how `operator()` is marked `const` inside. The member `value` is passed as a `const` object**, and that results in your error message since `InsertOpt` solely accepts non-`const` lvalues as the first argument.

However, when the first argument type is given as an lvalue reference, reference collapsing rules apply when accessing `value` through the `const` access path and the resulting type of `value` is "lvalue reference to non-const `ClassA`".

> Even when this change, the compiler generates the same error messages.

[Compiles for me](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f92f946f66eec858).

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the wrong type into `binary_function`:

```
struct  InsertOpt : binary_function<ClassA, int, ClassA&>
 //                                 ^^^^^^
{
        ClassA & operator( )( ClassA & c, int val ) const
        {
                c << val;
                return c;
        }
};
```

Your `operator()` takes a `ClassA&` but you are stating that it takes a `ClassA`. Those need to line up:

```
struct  InsertOpt : binary_function<ClassA&, int, ClassA&>
{
    // rest as before
};
```

Here's a much smaller example:

```
struct InsertOpt :
    std::binary_function<int, int, int&>
    //                   ^^^ if you change this to int&, it compiles
{
    int& operator()(int& a, int b) const {
        std::cout << b << std::endl;
        return a;
    }
};

int main() {
    const std::vector<int> v = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int a = 5;

    std::for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), std::bind1st(InsertOpt(), a));
}
```

Comment: No. I passed in the correct one. Please refer to my comments above. Even when this change, the compiler generates the same error messages.

Comment: @q0987 No, you didn't. You have to specify `Class&` there. If you're still getting an error after you add the `&`, then it's a separate problem. The `&` fixes it for me.

Comment: thank you for the example. I think the problem comes from my older compiler.